How to calculate the AVERAGE Time Spent In Flutter App
is there a way to calculate the daily average time the user opens the app and send the time spent on the app to the database?
I'm looking forward to gifting my users some tokens when they spend some time on my app
please, how can I achieve this?

Here's the code with detailed comments explaining each part. This code creates a Flutter app that displays a red page. It also calculates the duration of app usage between entering and exiting the application. When the app is closed or suspended, it calculates the duration and inserts it into the SQLite database. When the device connects to the internet, it sends the total usage time to the server.
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart'; // Import the connectivity package

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: RedPage(),
    );
  }
}

class RedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RedPageState createState() => _RedPageState();
}

class _RedPageState extends State<RedPage> {
  late Database _database;
  late DateTime _appStartTime; // Variable to store the app start time

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeDatabase(); // Initialize the SQLite database
    _appStartTime = DateTime.now(); // Record the app start time
    _sendDataToServerOnConnectivityChange(); // Listen for connectivity changes
  }

  // Initialize SQLite database
  Future<void> _initializeDatabase() async {
    _database = await openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'usage_data.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usage_data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, duration INTEGER)',
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  }

  // Calculate duration and insert usage data into the database
  Future<void> _insertUsageData() async {
    DateTime appEndTime = DateTime.now();
    int durationInSeconds = appEndTime.difference(_appStartTime).inSeconds;
    await _database.insert(
      'usage_data',
      {'duration': durationInSeconds},
    );
  }

  // Send data to server when connectivity changes
  void _sendDataToServerOnConnectivityChange() {
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      if (result == ConnectivityResult.mobile || result == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        _sendDataToServer();
      }
    });
  }

  // Send data to server
  Future<void> _sendDataToServer() async {
    final url = 'https://example.com/save-usage-data'; // Replace with your server URL
    try {
      // Fetch usage data from database
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> usageData = await _database.query('usage_data');
      // Convert duration to total usage time
      int totalUsageSeconds = 0;
      for (var data in usageData) {
        totalUsageSeconds += data['duration'] as int;
      }
      // Send total usage time to server
      await http.post(
        Uri.parse(url),
        body: {'total_usage_seconds': totalUsageSeconds.toString()},
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error sending data to server: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _insertUsageData(); // Insert usage data when the app is closed
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Red Page'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red, // Set background color to red
      ),
    );
  }
}

These comments explain each part of the code:

Import Dependencies: Import necessary packages including flutter/material.dart, sqflite/sqflite.dart, path/path.dart, http/http.dart, and connectivity/connectivity.dart.

MyApp Class: Defines the entry point of the application, returning a MaterialApp widget with the home set to RedPage.

RedPage Class: Represents the red page as a StatefulWidget.

_RedPageState Class: Implements the logic for the red page.

initState Method: Initializes the SQLite database, records the app start time, and listens for connectivity changes.

_initializeDatabase Method: Creates or opens the SQLite database.

_insertUsageData Method: Calculates the duration of app usage and inserts it into the database.

_sendDataToServerOnConnectivityChange Method: Listens for changes in network connectivity and triggers sending data to the server when the device is connected.

_sendDataToServer Method: Sends the usage data to the server.

dispose Method: Inserts usage data into the database when the app is closed or suspended.

build Method: Builds the UI of the red page, displaying a red-colored container.


I hope it will be helpful.

Thank You very much @Hossein, I'm grateful for helping me with great details on how I can achieve this.
You rock...

what about sending the total_usage_seconds at the end of the day to the database, if there was no internet connection at the end of the day when the user opened the app the following day, it sent yesterday's usage to the server before sending today's record?
what do you think of this, how can one achieve it?

Please, is it possible to reset the SQLite data every day?
